# Why I'm getting error when I'm using empty or isset function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

First, I use codeigniter when I am trying to use these functions.

```
if(empty($this->session->userdata('id'))):
```

When I call the page that contains this code, I'm getting error that is below

```
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /var/www/atlet/application/views/common/header.php on line 19
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

empty() only checks **variables**.

Description

> bool empty ( mixed $var )
>
> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is
>   considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.
>   empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

If you use it for anything else but variables it will result in a parse error. You cannot use empty() directly on a function's return value.

Try this instead

> if($this->session->userdata('id')==''):